# record search script using the SQL language in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a slight problem on the SQL server script, this script works if I select the radio button name will be looking for a first name but if I choose the company will seek based on the company name. this program for the hotel
following code

```
enter code here
#Region "GuestList"
Sub SearchRecord()
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Insert The Key", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Searching Record")
        TextBox1.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Try
        If rdoname.Checked = True Then
            dtadapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select firstname as [First Name],lastname as [Last Name], address as [Address], country as [Country], company as [Company], datein as [Date In], dateout as [Date Out], note as [Note] from tcekin Where fistname = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'", connection)
        Else
            dtadapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select firstname as [First Name],lastname as [Last Name], address as [Address], country as [Country], company as [Company], datein as [Date In], dateout as [Date Out], note as [Note] from tcekin Where company = '" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", connection)
        End If

        Dim tcekin As New DataTable
        tcekin.Clear()
        dtadapter.Fill(tcekin)
        If tcekin.Rows.Count = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Data Not Found", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Attention")
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox1.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Attention")
    End Try
End Sub 
#end region
```

on the search button, I've called SearchRecord but it doesn't work.

Comment: You are going to get slapped silly for this. Nice Sql Injection... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: +1 to astanders comment. Also "but it doesn't work" is hardly explanatory. Have you tried debugging? Does it hit a breakpoint inside this SearchRecord method? What error do you get?

Comment: What do you get?  An error or no results?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, need to study up on SQL injection.

```
tcekin.Rows.Count = Nothing
```

Count returns an integer doesn't it? So, it will not equal nothing, it will equal zero if no records are returned. It's possible you're getting no records and it's not firing your message box, etc.